# When $0\le h \le 0.01$, show that $e^h$ may be replaced by $1+h$ with an error of magnitude no greater than $0.6$% of h.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

When $0\le h \le 0.01$, show that $e^h$ may be replaced by $1+h$ with an error of magnitude no greater than $0.6$% of h.

use $e^{0.001} = 1.01$

What I did was :-

[image: Hope you will be able to understand my hand writing]

Comment: The error is not bounded by the next term; this is an error.  This technique is only valid for alternating series.  Instead use Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Use Taylor expansion upper bounded by geometric series to get: $\frac {e^h-1-h}{h}\le \frac h {2(1-h)}$.

Comment: How to do this?